# Parse google search via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, search

I need a get json/array from a google search.

```
$.get("http://google.com/", { "q": "query" },
   function(data){
     // PARSE ALL LINKS AND TITLE
   }, "json");
```

How I can do it?

I don't want to use ajax google api because that is deprecated and I need to get a ten results minimum.

Comment: You'll need to look into JSONP

Answer (score 2):

You will probably have to use the Google Custom Search API.  You can use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rh8tg/1/) example code as a starting point.

Comment: +1 for using api's as opposed to relying on url requests which could possibly change. Also note that the key provided in the example code works, but you should setup your own through the google custom search developer page.